# can't log in with my password during ssh connection

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openssh, multipass

my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is as follows

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

#Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#    SendEnv LANG LC_*
#    HashKnownHosts yes
#    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

my `student` user

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ finger student
Login: student                  Name: 
Directory: /home/student                Shell: /bin/bash
Never logged in.
No mail.
No Plan.
```

when establishing an SSH connection with my VM it should as me to enter a password which isn't the case I got this ?

```
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ multipass list 
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
ubuntu                  Running           10.226.208.153   Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ ssh student@10.226.208.153
student@10.226.208.153: Permission denied (publickey).
```

why I can't log in to student user with its password please help

Comment: @user535733 well then do you know how to fix it and which files to configure and edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set this server-side. If you're unable to connect to the server at all to make these changes then you might be out of luck doing this remotely.

Try forcing password authentication first though:

`ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no student@<ip-address>`

Once you've successfully connected through SSH you can change the server-side settings.

I suggest making a backup of the config first:

`sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.factory-defaults`

Now, edit the config file:

`sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Locate the line stating `PasswordAuthentication` and set it to `yes`.

`PasswordAuthentication yes`

Save your file and restart SSH

`sudo systemctl restart ssh`

See [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) for further info on ssh configuration.

Comment: thank you very much I didn't notice that I've to edit my `sshd_config` and set
`PasswordAuthentication` to `yes` 
I was editing the wrong file